# How to get an array with onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to get specific an array with onClick but the results always is undefined.
if the explanation is unclear, tell me please. i will fix it ! Thanks
here is the code

```js
 const chartType = ["Line", "Bar", "Pie", "Radar", "Doughnut", "Bubble"];
  const getType = (e) => {
    if (e.currentTarget === "Line") {
      console.log("true");
    }
  };
  const typeList = chartType.map((chart) => (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={getType}>{chart}</h1>
    </div>
  ));
```

u guys really helped me to solve this !! I appreciate it so much !!
I hope u all have a really nice day !!

Comment: what you mean by undefined ? can you paste the full code ? . Also what do you get when you do console.log(e.currentTarget) ?

Comment: I'm sorry aha i got the right answer from the other one ! thank u so much taking the time for answering !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `onClick` is actually grabbing the html element, that's why you're not getting any matches, when you click a particular `h1`, it returns `<h1>Foo</h1>`. To get the correct target you need `e.currentTarget.innerText`. Also since you are using React, please add a unique `key` prop to the iterated items.

Comment: Omg Thank u so much !! i solved the problem and i will add a unique`key` props now !

Comment: Sir , and i have another curious thing,  why do i have to add a unique `key`?? i've been wondering why u add it. if u have time to answer, please feel free !

Comment: To avoid React complaining in the console . Just kidding, the real reason to add it is that they help "identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed". It's just a little marker for React to render your components more efficiently. If you want to read a little more, check out https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Do not use `innerText`, because it is performance-heavy (as is calculates CSS). Just stick with using `textContent`.

Comment: omg Thank u so much !! you guys so helped me a lot !

Answer (score 1):

When onClick event happen, it fires [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) (you can see it when use `console.log(e)` from getType function). If you want to pass custom parameters, you should do like the following example:

```
  const chartType = ["Line", "Bar", "Pie", "Radar", "Doughnut", "Bubble"];
  const getType = (type) => {
    if (type === "Line") {
      console.log("true");
    }
  };
  const typeList = chartType.map((chart) => (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={() => getType(chart)}>{chart}</h1>
    </div>
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.currentTarget` returns the entire tag for example you will get this

```
<h1>Line</h1>
```

what you can do instead is to pass the chart as the argument to the getType.

```
const getType = (chart) => {
    if (chart === "Line") {
      console.log("true");
    }
  };

  const typeList = chartType.map((chart) => (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={() => getType(chart)}>{chart}</h1>
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: Oh that's another good solution !! thank u so much !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the chart type, you can use the `useState` hook to store the active state.

**Edit:** I changed `target.textContent` to `target.dataset.chartType` and added the data attribute called `data-chart-type` to each `<h1>`. This is safer than using rendered text.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const ChartTypes = ['Line', 'Bar', 'Pie', 'Radar', 'Doughnut', 'Bubble'];

const ChartTypeList = (props) => {
  const { activeType, handleSelect } = props;

  return (
    <div className="ChartTypeList">
      {ChartTypes.map((chartType) => (
        <h1
          key={chartType}
          className={activeType === chartType ? 'active' : ''}
          data-chart-type={chartType}
          onClick={handleSelect}>
            {chartType}
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [activeType, setActiveType] = useState(null);

  const handleSelect = ({ target }) => {
    setActiveType(target.dataset.chartType);
    console.log(`Changed type: "${target.dataset.chartType}"`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChartTypeList activeType={activeType} handleSelect={handleSelect} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4em !important; }

.App > .ChartTypeList {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ChartTypeList h1 {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.ChartTypeList h1:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ChartTypeList h1.active {
  color: unset;
  font-style: unset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: omg ! that's what i  wanna do now !! thank u so much !!

Comment: @KYUN the best way to approach this is to divide and conquer. Design your components as small building blocks.